# form_helper doubling action in CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, action

I am currently taking tutorials on how to use CodeIgniter and am taking a tutorial to  create a simple newsletter. For some reason when I hit the submit button a 404 page not found error is created and its obvious because the url doubles. Meaning, the url is:

`www.my_site.dev/index.php/email`

and when I hit the submit button is should be:

`www.my_site.dev/index.php/email/send`

but it doubles the url like this:

`www.my_site.dev/index.php/www.my_site.dev/index.php/email/send`

I am using the form helper:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

I just can't figure out where in the autoload or config files how to troubleshoot the reason for this or what to set to make the action appropriate.

To clear up any confusion [HERE](https://gist.github.com/70401ed7314fac8b46fa) is my view and controller.

Comment: I think you may need to be looking at your config instead of your view/controller. Especially the values for 'base_url', 'index_page' and 'uri_protocol'...

Comment: I added "http://" to the base url and it helped, but still doubling index. Here is the source code https://gist.github.com/be61876b9dfb3a886a1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding http:// to base_url is a start, but is base_url set to http://example.com/ or http://example.com/index.php ? (the latter one is incorrect)